# Printing issue when using :target pseudo-class

Tags: css, printing, target, pseudo-class

I'm trying to have a tabbed navigation using CSS only. I'm using :target pseudo-class for switching between tabs:

```
<div class="tabbed">
  <div id="tab1">
     <a href="#tab1">...</a>
     ...
  </div>
  <div id="tab2">
     <a href="#tab2">...</a>
     ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem however is when I'm trying to print the page. It always shows the last tab. This problem exists in Firefox but it is okay in chrome. In the CSS file, I use the following to address the issue; but it doesn't work.

```css
@media print {
  .tabbed > div:target > div {
    z-index:1;
  }
  .tabbed > div:not(:target) > div {
    z-index:0;
  }
}
```

Please let me know what could be done to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using `display` rather than `z-index` for your print styles?

I expect that this would do what you're asking:

```
@media print {
  .tabbed > div:target > div {
    display: block;
  }
  .tabbed > div:not(:target) > div {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't show the targeted tab but solved the issue of showing the last tab.